# Error while converting fasttext model to tensorflow-hub

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to convert facebooks' fast-text model to tensorflow-hub format. I have attached two main files for the purpose.

```
def _compute_ngrams(word, min_n=1, max_n=3):
    BOW, EOW = ('<', '>')  # Used by FastText to attach to all words as prefix and suffix
    ngrams = [] # batch_size, n_words, maxlen
    shape = word.shape # batch_size, n_sentenes, n_words
    maxlen = 0
    for b in range(shape[0]): # batch
        ngram_b = []
        for w in word[b]: 
            ngram = []
            extended_word = BOW + "".join( chr(x) for x in bytearray(w)) + EOW
            if w.decode("utf-8") not in global_vocab:
                for ngram_length in range(min_n, min(len(extended_word), max_n) + 1):
                    for i in range(0, len(extended_word) - ngram_length + 1):
                        ngram.append(extended_word[i:i + ngram_length])
            else:
                ngram.append(w.decode("utf-8") )
            ngram_b.append(ngram)
            maxlen = max(maxlen, len(ngram))
        ngrams.append(ngram_b)
    for batches in ngrams:
        for words in batches:
            temp = maxlen
            r = []
            while temp > len(words):
                r.append("UNK")
                temp = temp - 1
            words.extend(r)
    return ngrams

def make_module_spec(vocabulary_file, vocab_size, embeddings_dim=300,
                     num_oov_buckets=1):



     def module_fn():
        """Spec function for a token embedding module."""
        words = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.string, name="tokens")
        tokens = tf.py_func(_compute_ngrams, [words], tf.string)
        embeddings_var = tf.get_variable(
            initializer=tf.zeros([vocab_size + num_oov_buckets, embeddings_dim]),
            name=EMBEDDINGS_VAR_NAME,
            dtype=tf.float32
        )

        lookup_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(
            vocabulary_file=vocabulary_file,
            num_oov_buckets=num_oov_buckets,
        )
        ids = lookup_table.lookup(tokens)
        #combined_embedding = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embeddings_var, ids=ids), axis=2)
        combined_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embeddings_var, ids=ids)
        hub.add_signature("default", {"tokens": words},
                          {"default": combined_embedding})
    return hub.create_module_spec(module_fn)
```

The model is created as expected with tf-hub format.

But when I try to use the above created model, I get this error.

The sample testing code to use tf-hub model created above is attached below.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  module_url = "/home/sahil_wadhwa/tf-hub/tf_sent"
  embed = hub.Module(module_url)
  embeddings = embed([["Indian", "American"], ["Hello", "World"]])

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(embeddings)
    print(result)
    print(result.shape)
```

The error I get is here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/sahil_wadhwa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 195, in __call__
    raise ValueError("callback %s is not found" % token)

ValueError: callback pyfunc_0 is not found


         [[{{node module_apply_default/PyFunc}} = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_STRING], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Const)]]
```

Been stuck with this for a long time, any help here would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered on https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/222:

Hi Sahil,

the issue here is that tf.py_func cannot be serialized. Serializing
arbitrary Python functions is not supported (for multiple reasons).

I see you are creating ngrams from a token if not present in the vocabulary
(btw, are the ngrams actually in the FastText vocabulary to be looked up or
does it contain only full words?).

One way of solving this could be to rewrite your _compute_ngrams function
in TensorFlow (maybe you could use this directly or at least get some
inspiration:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/ngrams).